# How to send a notification from UIKit to a view in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit

I am trying to send a notification from UIViewcontroller to SwiftUI View after the user did pull to refresh.

```
 @objc private func fetchScheduleData(_ sender: UIRefreshControl) {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "didPullToRefreash"), object: nil)
     
    }
```

On SwiftUI view i trying to set this method .onchange()

```
   NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didPullToRefreashHelper), name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "didTapNotification"), object: nil)
```

But onChange it's not working. I am wondering i how i will do this.

Comment: The progress is simple and there is no strange approach for sending or getting a notification from UIKit to SwiftUI View, or vice versa. Do you have problems about sending or receiving a notification in general?

Comment: Yeah I am unable to send from UIKit to SwiftUI View

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest way of doing this would be to first, create the custom notification like this:

```
extension Notification.Name {
    static let didPullToRefresh = Notification.Name("didPullToRefresh")
}
```

That now lets you address it with dot notation. Next, in your VC:

```
 @objc private func fetchScheduleData(_ sender: UIRefreshControl) {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .didPullToRefresh, object: nil)
    }
```

Lastly, in your SwiftUI view:

```
.onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: .didPullToRefresh)) { _ in
    // If you are passing an object, this can be "notification in"

    // Do something here as a result of the notification
}
```

edit:

If you want to send a message in a SwiftUI view when a variable changed, then you could use `.onChange(of:)` like this:

```
.onChange(of: watchedStateVar) { value in
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .didPullToRefresh, object: value)
}
```